# Net Core 3.0 dependency injection interface that the dbcontext derived from

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Is there a way to dependency inject the interface a `DbContext` class is derived from in `Startup` class?

Below is the `DbContent` class

```
public partial class SRSDbContext : IdentityDbContext<SRSIdentityUser>, ISRSDbContext
{
    public SRSDbContext() 
    {

//...
```

In in the `Startup` class I tried using the code

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ISRSDbContext>(opts =>
        opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")));
```

But the `ISRSDbContext` interface was not recognized in the above line of code.

I like to register the `ISRSDbContext` for dependency injection using the a defined connection string in the `AppsSetting.json` file

Answer (score 2):

Use the `AddDbContext` overload that takes the interface and it's derived implementation

```
//...

services.AddDbContext<ISRSDbContext, SRSDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")));

//...
```

If the interface is registered in a separate library, also make sure that it is referenced by the library of the code making the call.

Comment: Hey thanks. I tried using Autofac with Net Core but I have been getting so many compile errors and headaches when using Autofac with .Net Core I just gave up. Autofac worked great when I used it with NetFramework but it gave me alot of problems with .Net Core. I posted question on Autofac blog about the problems and either got no answer or and answer that told me to look at autofac documents which provide little information